# HTML generated through PHP making dropdown option stay selected after submission

Tags: php, html

Here I have html that has been generated through PHP and my issue is that I want the dropdown's option to stay selected after form submission. What am I missing?

```
  $core_areas = array("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3");
  if (isset($_POST["core"]) && $_POST["core"] != "")
  {
    echo "<select name=\"core\" id=\"core\">
    <option value=\"\"> -Any- </option>";
    foreach($core_areas as $value) 
    {
      echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
    }   
  echo "</select>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<select name=\"core\" id=\"core\">
    <option value=\"\"> -Any- </option>";
    foreach($core_areas as $value) 
    {
      echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
    } 
    echo "</select>";
  }
```

Comment: Echo `selected="selected"` if `$_POST['core'] = somevalue` ???

Comment: echo "<option value=\"$value\"";
      if($_POST['core'] == $value) { echo "selected=\"selected\"";}
      echo ">$value</option>";
Thats what I changed the code to but no luck, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `selected` attribute to the selected option element.

```
echo "<option value=\"$value\" " .
  ($value == $_POST["core"] ? "selected" : "") . 
  ">$value</option>";
```